# Authentication and Authorization in Elixir without Phoenix

Tags: authentication, vue.js, authorization, elixir

I have an Elixir backend that provides API. My SPA is supported by Vue.js. I need to implement a simple user login system in Elixir. I found a lot of examples using Guardian but everyone is using Phoenix as framework. Can someone provide me an example on how to use it without Phoenix? Examples with other libraries are also appreciated

Comment: Can you share some code that shows the structure of your API (the web request/response flow). I can then tailor an answer for your specific needs.

Comment: Do you have something working right now to handle web requests in your Elixir backend? If so, what are you using for a web server?

Answer (score 0):

Everything depends of what kind of auth you want to have and how you communicate with the Elixir backend. Assuming that you have Elixir running on somekind of webserver all you need to have is an interface between backend and front eg.

```
# function that checks whether user is authenticated
def authenticate(user, password) do
  password_hash = give_me_password_hash_for_user(user) 
  # how you want to retrieve that - maybe Ecto? Ecto is not a part of Phoenix
  if Comeonin.Bcrypt.checkpw(password, password_hash) do # using here Comeonin
    happy_path()
  else
    unauthorized_path()
  end
end
```

And of course you need to pass the information that the user is logged in - keep it in session or send the token (jwt or Phoenix - whatever) to each API call.